# Arduino drone project

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am working on a drone project and currently choosing a board to use. Is it possible to use an Arduino Nano for all needs which are:

- Gyroscope and Accelerometer
- Barometer (as an altimeter)
- Digital magnetometer
- WiFi (to send telemetry for processing)
- GPS module
- 4 motors (of course)

P.S:

1. I know nothing about Arduino. However I have a good ASM, C/C++, programming background and I used to design analog circuits.
2. I would like to avoid using ready-made flight controllers.

Comment: You will run out of memory on an Arduino Nano with the list of needs you describe. Speed perspective, maybe ok.

Comment: What about spi memory? Would it solve memory issue?

Comment: There are three types of memory in these chips. Flash, SRAM and EEPROM. The one I suspect you will run out of is the flash and probably SRAM. You can use SPI RAM to help with the SRAM part, but the flash needs to be on the chip. A good page to have a look at is https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory which is quite simple explanation. The other part about SPI is that again uses up pins. Have you mapped them out yet to see what will work together yet? (see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano as a strarting point).  Happy to help if you don't understand parts.

Comment: Realistically speaking, using a general purpose evaluation board or development board is unwise - they are heavy which means an unnecessarily large vehicle.  If you really want to build something flyable, you should be using a board intended for that purpose - either one sold for that, or one you design.  And at minimum you should study what goes into existing, working designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin count should not be too much of an issue if using I²C sensors, they would simply all share the same two pins (SCL, SDA).

I agree that the RAM could be a limitation, the processing power (30 MIPS for an arduino uno) should be sufficient.

On an arduino mega, the APM project ran for years with great success.

I believe it's possible to do a very simplified drone flight controller with an Arduino nano and several I²C sensors + GPS.

But even with a more advanced microcontroller it's not a trivial task.

*** If you still want to try the experiment, have a look at openlrs project : https://code.google.com/p/openlrs/ . It's quite old (there are several derived projects too), but it runs on a hardware similar to arduino uno (atmega328). It provides RC control, and quad flight controller with i²c gyroscopes, accelerometers (based on wii remote), and barometer.

It also parse data from the GPS, but afaik it doesn't provide autonomous navigation but it should be possible to add it without too much additional work.

edit : about the available RAM.

I understand that at first sight 2kb of RAM seems a very small amount. And a part of it is already used by Arduino, for example the serial library provides two 64 bytes FIFO, using some RAM. Same for the Wire (I²C) library, although a smaller amount. It also uses some RAM for stack and temporary variables, even for simple tasks such as float operations. Let's say in total it will use 500 bytes.

But then what amount of RAM is really required ?
- It will have a few PIDs regulators, let's say that each one will use 10 float parameters to store PID parameters, current value etc. So it gives 40 bytes per regulator, and let's say we need 10 regulators. We should need less, but let's take that example. So that's 400 bytes.
-Then it will need to parse GPS messages. A GPS message is maximum 80 bytes. Let's allow a buffer of 80 bytes for GPS parsing, even if it would be possible to do most of the parsing "on-the-fly" without storing it in a buffer.
-Let's keep some room for the GPS and sensors data, 300 bytes which seems generous, as we don't need to store them in floats. But we can put in it the current GPS coordinates, altitude, number of satellites, pitch, roll etc
-Then some place for application data, such as home GPS coordinates, current mode, stick positions, servo values etc.

The rest is mostly calculations, going from the current GPS coordinates and target coordinates to a target altitude, heading etc. And then feed the PIDs to the calculated pitch and roll. But this doesn't require additional RAM.

So I would say it's possible to do a very simple flight controller using 1280 bytes. And if I was too low or forgot some aspects, there's still more than 700 bytes available.

Certainly not saying it's easy to do, every aspect will have to be optimized, but it doesn't look impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a trick to make all of that work on a Nano. I would suggest you look at http://ardupilot.com/ they have built a lot of cool thinks around the ARM chip (same as an Arduino) and there are some pretty active communities on there as well.

Comment: Why would that be a trick? Because of the processing power? I'm looking into the same project, and would really like to use the Nano too. :)

Comment: @ErlendD. I guess number of arduino outputs will be the first issue

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't run out of pins (and you probably would), by the time you wrote the code for the motors and the GPS, you will run out of RAM.

And that's not even getting into the CPU speed, which is nowhere near enough. As mentioned in the other answer, you'll be better off with a Cortex M-x CPU.

Arguably, you could use a few Nanos, one per task, but chaining them together would be a nice mess...